# Название причесок: в кавычках или без?

Tags: пунктуация

"Прическа каре" — по-моему, "каре" в кавычки не берут, а ведь это название прически. Или "он подстрижен под полубокс". Так нужно ли вообще брать в кавычки названия причесок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каре, полубокс, боб, хвост - всё это термины, они пишутся без кавычек. В кавычках, как правильно заметила Инна, пишутся названия индивидуальные, придуманные именно для этого момента, например, "Шикарное каре на ножке " Идеал" принесло ей успех".

Answer (score 2):

Коса, хвост, пучок, наверное,  считаются очень простыми причёсками и пишутся без кавычек. Но можно увидеть в журналах причёсок такие подписи под фотографиями моделей:
 "Вдохновение", "Романтика".